# Plot boxplot for multiple numerical categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe containing n columns. I would like to plot my data using boxplots for each element (X1, X2, X3,...X14). I am not able to figure out how to use my dataframe for multiple categories.

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.867 | 0.568 | 0.674 | 0.976 | 0.332 |
| 0.546 | 0.532 | 0.653 | 0.994 | 0.848 |
| 0.546 | 0.532 | 0.653 | 0.994 | 0.848 |
| 0.546 | 0.532 | 0.653 | 0.994 | 0.848 |
| 0.546 | 0.532 | 0.653 | 0.994 | 0.848 |

I found one example with which I tried the following, but it is not working.

```
df <- data.frame(Xs = 1:14)
df <- melt(df , id.vars = 'Xs', variable_name = 'elements')

Test <- ggplot(df, aes(Xs, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape)
df %>%
  melt() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Generated random data:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X2 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X3 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X4 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X5 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X6 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X7 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X8 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X9 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X10 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X11 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X12 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X13 = runif(14, 0, 1),
                 X14 = runif(14, 0, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the fast reply! This is working nicely. Now I have to check if this can work with my larger dataframe. The one I posted in my question is a shorter version of the full dataset. I will post here again once I do it tomorrow.

Comment: @EKviz, No problem! It should work if you just have 14 numerical columns like in your sample data.

Comment: Hei, the code you provided worked for my dataset perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution provided by @Quinten worked for my dataset (visually), but somehow the summary of the boxplots (median, mean, etc) were not correct. So I searched some more and ended up using the pivot_longer function for my dataset.

```
df %>% select(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5) %>%
  pivot_longer(., cols = c(X1, X2, X3, X4, X5), 
  names_to = "Var", values_to = "Val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Var, y = Val)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

This gave the correct distribution of my dataset (mean, medians etc.).